# Angular @ng-bootstrap error running tests with NgbPopoverModule

Tags: angular, typescript, popover, ng-bootstrap

I have a component that uses the NgbPopoverModule.  The component works fine and displays the popover.  When setting up my tests I include the module but i get the following error `NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbPopoverConfig!`

I've tried adding the popover config as below but neither work.

```
  providers: [
     NgbPopoverConfig
  ]
```

and

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NgbPopoverConfig, useValue:
      {
        placement: 'top',
        triggers: 'click',
        container: null
      }
    }
  ]
```

My imports are as follows

```
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes( [] ),
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgbPopoverModule
  ]
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Import calling `forRoot()` . This returns an `ModuleWithProviders` which adds the *providers* provided by `NgbPopoverModule`.

```
imports: [
    ...
    NgbPopoverModule.forRoot()
    ...
  ]
```